# Custom Drupal7 Module: How to use PHPTemplate engine for generating a custom template?

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm a little unsure, and the documentation on hook_theme is quite.. widespread.

I want to be able to feed my module a custom .tpl.php (template) file, along with some variables, to generate/render some HTML that can be sent out in an email.

How would I go about with this? I assume that I have to use hook_theme, but I'm a little unsure how to actually render and access the HTML without displaying it anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, from a different helpful source:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme
 *
 * @param $existing
 * @param $type
 * @param $theme
 * @param $path
 * @return array
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
  return array(
    'name_of_theme_function' => array(
      'variables' => array('name_of_array' => array()),
      'template' => 'name-of-my-template',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/theme'
    ),
   )
}

/**
 * My Module Callback
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function MYMODULE_callback_function(){
  $output = array('array value', 'array value 2');

  $output = array(
    '#theme' => 'name_of_theme_function',
    '#name_of_array' => $output
  );

  return render($output);
}

/*** Inside the template name-of-my-template.tpl.php
dpm($name_of_array)
```